# Line breaks don't exist on input from FTP file (Perl)

Tags: perl, character-encoding, escaping

I downloaded a csv file using Net::FTP.  When I look at this file in text editor or excel or even when I cut/paste it has line breaks and looks like this:
    000000000G911|06
    0000000000CDR|25|123
    0000000000EGP|19

When I read the file in Perl it sees the entire text as one line like this:

000000000G911|060000000000CDR|25|1230000000000EGP|19

I have tried reading it using

```
tie @lines, 'Tie::File', "C:/Programs/myfile.csv", autochomp=>0  or die "Can't read file: $!\n";  
foreach $l (@lines1)  
    {print "$l\n";  
}
```

and

```
open FILE, "`<`$filename" or die $!;    
my @lines=`<`FILE>;  
foreach $l (@lines)  
{print "$l\n";  
}  
close FILE;
```

Comment: Why do you have backticks in your `open` and readline statements? I hope that's not in your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file has line breaks in a format that Perl is not recognizing because it is coming from a different operating system.  The other programs are automatically detecting the different line break format, but Perl doesn't do that.

If you have [`Net::FTP`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) perform the transfer in ASCII mode (e.g. `$ftp->ascii` to enable this mode), this should be taken care of and corrected for you.

Alternatively, you can figure out what is being used for line breaks and then set the special `$/` variable to that value.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that I'm using $ftp->ascii.  How can I see what the file is using for line breaks?

Comment: @HeatherSpence Use `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $l;` It will write out the whitespace.

Comment: Note: if ASCII mode is not correctly translating the line breaks, maybe that means the line breaks are not in the native format for the server, either.